# Laravel Get the total of price columns using array of id's

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have jquery that send array of ids to controller,every id has price in database, I want to get the total of the prices of those ids that send by ajax, as you see the array of ids like this below, I dont know what to write in the controller to get the total of prices of these ids

```
array:3 [▼
 0 => "36"
  1 => "274"
   2 => "38"
 ]


 $('.option__choices input').on('change', function() { 
   var checkid = [];

        $.each($("input[name='customizecheck']:checked"), function(){            
            checkid.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:'/writer/getcustPrice',
            type: 'get',
              data: {
                    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'checkid': checkid
                },

       success: function(data){
            },

            error:function(data){
            }

      });  });
```

Controller

```
 public function getcustPrice(Request $request)
   {

 if($request->ajax())
{

 foreach($request->input('checkid') as $key => $value) {

  $allids = CustomizeProduct::findOrFail($request->input('checkid'));        

  $price=$allids->customize_price;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a total variable and need to add price in that for each passed checkId as below:

```
public function getcustPrice(Request $request)
{
   if($request->ajax()){
        $totalPrice = 0;
        foreach($request->input('checkid') as $key => $value) {

            $allids = CustomizeProduct::findOrFail($value);
            $price = $allids->customize_price;
            $totalPrice += $price;

        }
        return Response::json( $totalPrice );

    }
}
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this way,

```
$price = 0;
foreach($request->input('checkid') as $key => $value) {

  $allids = CustomizeProduct::findOrFail($request->input('checkid'));        

  $price += $allids->customize_price;

}
return $price;
```